# определения страны по телефонному номеру

Tags: java, spring

Нужна помощь, ибо не представляю что и как делать дальше.
Есть задача:
Написать микросервис для определения страны по телефонному номеру.
Пользователь вводит номер телефона, система валидирует его и показывает страну или сообщение об ошибке.
Для кодов стран воспользуйтесь таблицей на странице
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes,
необходимо загружать из неё данные каждый раз при запуске сервиса.

Нефункциональные требования:

Backend :
Java 8+
Spring Boot
Maven/Gradle
HTTP, RESTful сервис с JSON-форматом данных.

Frontend :
HTML
JavaScript
CSS

Вспомогательные библиотеки - на Ваше усмотрение, однако нельзя использовать те,
которые являются решением задачи (например, Google Phone Validator и т.д.)
Нашёл код, который вытягивает таблицу из страницы

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes").get();
    Element table = document.select("table.wikitable").get(1);
    Elements body = table.select("tbody");
    Elements rows = body.select("tr");

    for(Element row: rows){
        System.out.println(row.select("th").text());
        System.out.println(row.select("td").text());
```

В консоль выводится в таком виде:

```
Country, Territory or Service Code Time Zone DST

Afghanistan +93 UTC+04:30 
Åland Islands +358 18 UTC+02:00 UTC+03:00
Albania +355 UTC+01:00 UTC+02:00
Algeria +213 UTC+01:00
```

Годится ли это для выполнения? И как эти строки сравнить с вводимым кодом от юзера? Как вывести соответствующую страну (в смысле, её из этой же строки брать или опять из таблицы)? В общем, не представляю что делать. Любая помощь пожалуйста.

Comment: А чего у Вас коды стран преобразовываются в зоны времени, а? И Финляндию обидели, сделали придатком Аландских островов...

Comment: Это не у меня, это таблица оттуда -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes . И у Аландских островов код +358 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При считывании таблицы Вы можете закешировать данные куда-то, например, в `java.util.Map` и при валидации данных от пользователя проверять код.

```
package com.somepackage;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document document =
                Jsoup.connect(
                        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes").get();
        Element table = document.select("table.wikitable").get(1);
        Elements body = table.select("tbody");
        Elements rows = body.select("tr");

        Map<String, String> codes =
                new HashMap<>();
        for (Element row : rows) {
            Elements columns = row.select("td");
            if (columns.size() > 2) {
                String name = columns.get(0).text();
                String code = columns.get(1).text();
                codes.put(name, code);
            }
        }
        codes.forEach((n,c) -> System.out.println(n + " -> " + c));
    }

}
```